# python usage of percentage sign- doesn't appear to be modulo or string formatting

Tags: python

What does a `%` sign mean in python when it is not a modulo or a string formatter? I came across it in this baffling block of code in the `timeit` module:

```py
# Don't change the indentation of the template; the reindent() calls
# in Timer.__init__() depend on setup being indented 4 spaces and stmt
# being indented 8 spaces.
template = """
def inner(_it, _timer):
    %(setup)s
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        %(stmt)s
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
"""

def reindent(src, indent):
    """Helper to reindent a multi-line statement."""
    return src.replace("\n", "\n" + " "*indent)
```

I have searched Google and SO for what this operator is, but no luck. I am using python 2.6.1 .

Comment: It is string formatting here. Notice the `"""` symbols? There is a variable `template` in the code, and it is being assigned a string. The `%` is used for formatting, just like usual. It's just that the actual substitution **hasn't happened yet** in this part of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is also string formatting.  The `%(var)` syntax is used when you pass a dictionary of format replacers, and each is replaced by name:

```
>>> "%(foo)s is replaced" % {'foo': 'THIS'}
'THIS is replaced'
```

This is the "mapping key" usage described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Comment: Oh. Right. I was so distracted by the odd technique of writing out an entire method in a string that I forgot it could be string formatting because it would be replaced later in the program. I thought, "Oh cool- a new `%` usage." Kinda dumb on my part. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewAdams I wouldn't say it's dumb since `%` formatting was deprecated for a good reason.

Answer (score 4):

This is its use as a format specifier.

```
>>> print '%(b)s %(a)s' % { 'a': "world", 'b': "hello" }
hello world
```